# Warnings ActionBarActivity in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Why ActionBarActivity in eclipse [Show this way In the picture!!!](http://www12.0zz0.com/2015/06/20/13/964134730.png)

[image]

Does this mean there is an error?

Answer (score 2):

It means that [`ActionBarActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) is deprecated. You should use [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) instead.

Note: If you hover your mouse over the warning icon to the left of the line number, Eclipse should display a warning message with options on what you can do.